# how to copy the whole row of widgets by clicking button, and then get access to new widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Say we have a dialog with a row of parameters that user changes.

[image: Dialog]

These parameters have some connections between each other. The user can add a row with button 'add type' as many times as he needs. The aim is to copy the whole row of widgets on button clicked, saving a connection between widgets, and having the opportunity to access this parameters (in this example - print a text of 2nd lineEdit including those in new rows in the interpreter.

Please, help with my function add_row

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from dialog_1 import Ui_Form


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['123','456','qwerty'])
        self.ui.comboBox.activated.connect(lambda: self.ui.lineEdit1.setText(self.ui.comboBox.currentText()))
        self.ui.lineEdit2.returnPressed.connect(lambda: print(self.ui.lineEdit2.text()))

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

    def add_row(self):
        pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Dialog()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A dialog_1.py file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
  def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(774, 169)
    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
    self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 661, 61))
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
    self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
    self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
    self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
    self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton2, 0, 4, 1, 1)
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame)
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 5, 1, 1)
    self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.frame)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.checkBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.checkBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.checkBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
    self.checkBox.setText("")
    self.checkBox.setAutoRepeat(False)
    self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.checkBox, 0, 6, 1, 1)
    self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
    self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit1")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
    self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit2, 0, 8, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
    self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton1, 0, 9, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 20, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

  def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
    self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("Form", "..."))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "#1"))
    self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("Form", "..."))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Add Type"))enter code here
```

Comment: show what you tried even if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.rows = []
        self.row_count = 1

    def add_row(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"#{self.row_count+1}")
        line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("foo")

        self.rows.append([label, line_edit, push_button])
        for i, item in enumerate(self.rows[-1]):
            self.ui.gridLayout_5.addWidget(item, self.row_count, i, 1, 1)
        self.row_count += 1
```

I think you can achieve what you want with this. It just requires some tweaking to work properly but I can't do it because I don't have the `.ui` file.

Comment: Thank you! I put my code for add_row in the next answer. The last thing that I don't understand - how to name new widgets, created by user. For ex. what would be the name of lineEdit2 in row #3?

Comment: You don't have to name them. You can reach them by using `self.rows`. For example if you want to reach second item in last row (`QLineEdit` in my example): `self.rows[-1][1].textChanged.connect(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded with this code:

```
def add_row(self):
    new_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"#{self.ui.row_count+1}")
    new_lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    new_pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
    new_comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    new_checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
    new_lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    new_pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()


    self.ui.rows.append([new_label, new_lineEdit1, new_pushButton2, new_comboBox, new_checkBox, new_lineEdit2, new_pushButton1])
    for i, item in enumerate(self.ui.rows[-1]):
        self.ui.gridLayout_5.addWidget(item, self.ui.row_count, i, 1, 1)
    self.ui.row_count += 1

    new_comboBox.addItems(['123','456','qwerty'])
    new_comboBox.activated.connect(lambda: new_lineEdit1.setText(new_comboBox.currentText()))
    new_lineEdit2.returnPressed.connect(lambda: print(new_lineEdit2.text()))
```

The last thing remained unclear:
for example, what if I need to copy a text from *lineEdit2 in the row #3* to some other lineEdit outside the row? [Dialog with lineEdit3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt9FY.jpg)

What should I put instead "?????"

```
self.ui.?????.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.ui.lineEdit3.setText(self.ui.?????.text())))
```

Comment: I answered your question under my post. I think you will solve your problem with it. And I have a suggestion for you: Give a name to your layout in QtDesigner so that your code don't rely on auto-generated name (`gridLayout_5`). Because there is no guarantee that the name of your layout will be `gridLayout_5` next time you generate `.py` file.